# Selector inside a selector (CSS)

Tags: css

I have am running the selector

```
.element a:after { content: url("...."); }
```

But what I am wanting to make sure is that it clears the :after on the last of type, and so I want something like this to happen:

```
.element a:after:last-of-type { content: url("....") } /* Note that I am changing the image to a blank spacer */
```

How can I do this?

Matt

Comment: you should use `.element a:last-of-type:after`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change the order of the pseudo classes/elements. Put `:last-of-type` before `:after`:

[**WORKING EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/Bh9xk/)

```
.element a:last-of-type:after {
    content: url("....");
}
```

Based on the HTML structure you posted in the comments: [**(example)**](http://jsfiddle.net/HJmG5/)

```
<ul id="breadCrumb">
    <li><a href="#">Dashboard</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
</ul>
```

You would use `:last-of-type` on the `li` element:

```
#breadCrumb li a:after {
    content: url('....');
}

#breadCrumb li:last-of-type a:after {
    content: url("....");
}
```

Comment: Hi Josh, it doesn't seem to be working for me,
When I run the last-of-type:after it changes all of their content.

Comment: @Matthew Interesting - it works here with the same code you just posted: http://jsfiddle.net/F8XdX/ Can you post the HTML?

Comment: I've updated the jSfiddle with my CSS and my HTML, unfortunately the images won't link for now but I'm sure you'll get the point. Let me know.

Comment: Thank you very much!
I see where I went wrong, have a fantastic day.